# How to force Motorola's Ready For to show up on the phone screen?

Tags: motorola, scrcpy

#### TL;DR

Is there any way to force a Motorola phone to launch the desktop mode on the phone itself instead of relying on the Windows app?

#### What Ready For is

Ready For is Motorola's desktop mode (Like Samsung's Dex). It's not a separate launcher and there are three ways of connecting to it normally:

- Directly connecting to a monitor through HDMI
- Connecting to a Windows PC through an App from Microsoft's app store
- Connecting through WiFi to a compatible monitor or TV.

#### Why I need this

- My specific phone model (Edge 40) can't connect through HDMI (and I'm still mad about it).
- My personal computer is Linux and they don't offer a Linux app.
- My job computer is Windows, but Microsoft's app store is blocked in it.

#### What I want to do instead

If I could somehow force desktop mode on the phone itself, I could then use [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) to share the screen both on Windows and Linux to work with it.

Thanks

#### Edit

I was able to install Ready For on my job computer through `winget`. Unfortunately, it seems Motorola's screen casting solution is not well ironed out yet and it's extremely slow.

Good news though is that I was able to capture Ready For's desktop on `scrcpy` as it is detected as a hidden second display.

This sort of resolves my ultimate objective (on Windows at least), but does not answer my question, so I'll keep it here instead of in a dedicate answer.

Comment: You could try to manually download the `.appx`/ .AppxBundle file and install it manually on the Windows computer. Usually companies only block the store, not the appx installation.

Comment: Thanks, @Robert. I'll try that out later on. How do I download the `.appx`? If I try the store on a browser, it redirects to the desktop store (the "install" button uses `ms-windows-store` protocol that directly opens the store and not an HTTP URL)

Comment: There are third party programs available which can download appx programs from MS store. See e.g. here: https://woshub.com/how-to-download-appx-installation-file-for-any-windows-store-app/

Comment: Alright, thanks! I'll check it out

Comment: That worked. It will work great for Windows, thanks! It's slower than scrcpy, but it's an almost complete desktop environment feeling. Now, for Linux I guess only way to do it would be a proper answer to the question...